# Using computed column in CharIndex

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to first Concat two columns and then perform a search operation using `CHARINDEX` on that calculated column as below :

```
 SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName FROM Customer WHERE CHARINDEX('Martin', FullName, 1) <> 0
```

however, I am unable to use the calculated column (FullName) inside the `CHARINDEX` function.

The error I am getting is :

> Invalid column name 'FullName'.

What mistake am I committing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to Scott's answer, you can just move the concat to the where clause as well.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName 
FROM Customer 
WHERE CHARINDEX('Martin', CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName), 1) <> 0
```

Or, as a derived table.

```
SELECT FullName 
FROM(
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName 
FROM Customer) x
WHERE CHARINDEX('Martin', FullName, 1) <> 0
```

As for **why** you can't use the alias in the `WHERE` clause, it's because queries don't *start* with `SELECT`. Your `WHERE` is evaluated before the column list is selected.

- [Julia Evans: SQL Queries don't start with select](https://jvns.ca/blog/2019/10/03/sql-queries-don-t-start-with-select/)
- [Similar Question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16161938/how-to-use-alias-column-name-in-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 2):

Try encapsulating your `CONCAT` logic inside a common table expression like this:

```
;WITH _cte
AS (
    SELECT CONCAT (FirstName,' ',LastName) AS FullName
    FROM Customer
    )
SELECT *
FROM _cte
WHERE CHARINDEX('Martin', FullName, 1) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check both individually.

```
SELECT CONCAT(FirstName, ' ', LastName) as FullName 
FROM Customer 
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Martin%' OR LastName LIKE '%Martin'
```

Comment: On second thought my edit probably didn’t matter and you could use = which could use a covering index.